# Copy files from UNC path to C:\ and Program files (x86) folder within a remotly generated New-PSSession

Tags: powershell, unc, copy-item

I am writing a script, that creates a new VM, connects to it via `New-PSSession` and runs serveral Commands to alter a few settings and copy folders from a UNC path to the local `C:` and `C:\Program files (x86)`.

Everything works fine expect the copy part - I get an error saying

> permission denied.

I run the script itself as domain admin and the credentials I pass also has domain admin rights.

For example:

```
$source = '\\server\share'
$cred = Get-Credential
$pss = New-PSSession -ComputerName "$computername" -Credential $cred
Invoke-Command -Session $pss -ScriptBlock {
    Copy-Item "$source\FOLDER" -Destination 'C:\FOLDER' -Recurse -Force -
Credential 
$cred
```

Even if I pass the cedentials it fails. A quick search results in *"use robocopy"*, but in my opinion it must be possible to copy files from a UNC path to a local directory with PowerShell even if that directory is basically protected by Microsoft.

Comment: The code snippet you posted is both incomplete and malformed. Please show a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass the variable to the remote session:

`invoke-Command -Session $pss -Args $source -ScriptBlock{Copy-Item "$args[0]\FOLDER" ...}`

otherwise $source is considered a variable in the remote session and since it doesn't exist there ps will try to copy from \Folder

Comment: ah, yep, my fault. Actually I did that in my current Script and the variable is known and resolvable inside the remote session.

Comment: I got the same error with an interactive session using

    enter-pssession

and solved it with 

    new-psdrive -name Y -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $source 
    -Credential $cred
    set-location Y:
 
doing this I am able to copy files.
I put this into my new-pssession and let my script run. It'll now take a time and I'll write as soon as i got an result

I

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use -ToSession parametr without entering to PSSession.

```
$ses = New-PSSession -ComputerName WorkStation


Copy-Item -ToSession $ses -Destination C:\users\TempUser\Documents\ -Path '\\10.0.0.1\share\' -Recurse
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please also take some time to add a short explanation to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for Copy-Item is:

```
-Destination $($(dir "env:programfiles(x86)").value + "\Avest\AvPCM_nces\")
```